# Passing in a function only works if inlined, not if created by higher-order function

Tags: kotlin, higher-order-functions

Two methods were sharing the exact same logic for handling a function returning a `CompletableFuture`, so I thought I would extract it into a common function that would return this logic.

Extracting the main body of the method into a common function works fine:
[image: extracted]
All breakpoints are hit and the code works.

I then extracted this closure creation into a separate function, `myFunction`, which is basically returning a function that [matches what the `whenComplete` signature requires](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-).

```
        }.whenComplete(myFunction(ctx, payload))
    }

    private fun myFunction(
        ctx: ChannelHandlerContext,
        payload: DataReport
    ) = { result:SaveDataReportResult, throwable: Throwable? ->
        extracted(throwable, result, ctx, payload)
    }
```

After doing this, none of the breakpoints of `extracted` are hit and the body of the method is not executed (as in no logger statements are being exercised).

This is quite counter-intuitive, so what am I missing here? I ran this by a colleague, and he could also not fault the code. Not all that familiar with Kotlin, I have to admit, so there might be some details I have missed.

Comment: Is it just that it doesn't stop at the breakpoints, or does it also not execute the code?

Comment: Both :) The code is not executed and the breakpoints are not hit.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with a simple example, but maybe if you start with a simple example and incrementally change it into your code, you can figure out where the problem is. https://pl.kotl.in/AK0yNQt7x

Comment: Absolutely, thanks, will have a try at that. Was hoping of course there was some dead simple mistake I was doing that someone could spot, but I guess I was not that lucky.

Comment: You might wanna try explicit types in multiple places to ensure your understanding is the same as the compiler's